# How to create a co-occurrence matrix from a Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a co-occurrence matrix from some tuples, see below:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(
  Array("101","103","105"), Array("102","105"),Array("101","102","103","105"))
val coocMatrix = new ArrayBuffer[(String, Int)]()

// map
rdd.collect().foreach(x => 
  { for(i <- 0 to x.length-1)
  { for(j <- i+1 to x.length-1)
  { coocMatrix += (x(i)+"#"+x(j), 1) }}

// convert to rdd again
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(coocMatrix)

// reduce
vall matrix = rdd2.collect().groupByKey()
```

So we get following data finally

```
(101#103,2),(101#105,2),(102#105,2),(101#102,1),
(103#105,2),(102#103,1),(102#105,1)
```

This algorithm is terribly slow because it's O(n*n) and infeasible when there 2 million tuples. Is there any algorithm to calculate this co-occurrence matrix?

Answer (score 7):

The `combinations` method allows you to extract the list of pairs occurring in a given array. After that you can reduceByKey

```
    rdd.flatMap{_.combinations(2).map{pairs=>(pairs.mkString("#"),1)}}.
    reduceByKey(_+_)
```

Comment: This works, and much faster than the 2-loops! Amazing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If words are considered co-occurred  if they are in the same line (not rdd), how would I do that?